# How do I setup a read only private docker registry using just HTTP?

Tags: python, nginx, docker

I am running my own private registry and wish to deliver the image data over plain HTTP instead of using the docker-registry python application. Is there a way to configure nginx (or any other web server) to deliver registry image data?

nginx can do a much better job scaling delivery of image data than the python docker-registry application can.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the required missing files (images and tags) which describe the image layer data. Here is a simple bash snippet to generate the missing pieces of information.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    REGISTRY_SERVER=localhost:5000
    REGISTRY_TOPDIR=/srv/docker-registry-storage/
    touch $REGISTRY_TOPDIR/_ping
    find $REGISTRY_TOPDIR -name _index_images -type f | while read F
    do
            D="$(dirname "$F")"
            B="$(basename "$D")"
            P="$(echo "$D" | sed "s,^$REGISTRY_TOPDIR,/v1/,")"
            curl -s http://$REGISTRY_SERVER/$P/images > $D/images
            curl -s http://$REGISTRY_SERVER/$P/tags > $D/tags
    done
```

Last but not least, you need to make the $REGISTRY_TOPDIR web accessible. Using 
nginx this looks like:

```
    location /v1/ {
            alias /srv/docker-registry-storage/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow 10.0.0.0/8;
            deny all;
    }
```

Finally, test it out. Note that if you push in image without a USER in the path parameter, it will insert "library" in its place on the file system.

```
docker pull someserver.example.net/library/template
```